# How to turn off retina resolution in iMac 5k?

Tags: macos, imac, 5k

I've started using many charts softwares recently. I open 5 charts at a time and my iMac 5k gets laggy whenever I do that. I checked with iStat Menus and it looks like my video card's ram is almost maxed out. Since my non-retina mac os computers work just fine with more than 5+ charts, I assume Retina resolution is taking too much memory.

How do I turn off retina mode and just use 2560x1440?

I've tried pressing "option" key in Display preference, but it looks like it's still using retina mode.

Comment: Have you checked if manual calclation has been set on the other machines?

Comment: It’s highly unlikely the GPU is slow, can you reboot and run only safari and run motion mark and edit the results of that after boot and when “slow”? http://browserbench.org/MotionMark/

Comment: @SolarMike Hi Mike, what is manual calculation?

Comment: @bmike GPU is fast when I run a single application. There is no problem with benchmark. The problem is that my vram is almost maxed out when the process usage (GPU) is less than 15%. Charting softwares just take a lot of memory.

Comment: Just thinking progs like excel can use a lot of processor re-calculating cells

Comment: @SolarMike processor usage looks very low. It's just the memory stays at 90%+. If I close some of the windows, it lowers to 60~70% range and it feels fast. Using very low resolution (1280x720) drops the memory usage to 60% without closing any windows.

Answer (score 1):

The retina display causes any somewhat graphic intensive apps to be laggy. It's a major design flaw. You can fix this by right clicking on any app and clicking "get info". Then click on "open in low resolution".

You'll be surprised to see how fast apps run now. It will look not as clear, however. The retina sucks. My 2011 macbook ran everything better because it didn't have a retina display.